# Draw Polyline in swift ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps

i am developing app which is using MKMapView i want to draw route on map using google map api i have not implemented GoogleMaps SDK to my app.
I am getting one error like `Thread 7: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1,address=0x0)`
Mycode is :

```
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=23.0061,72.5647&destination=23.0424534104078,72.5647906513495&sensor=true&mode=driving")!
        var request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            var err: NSError
            var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

            var routesArray = jsonResult.objectForKey("routes") as! NSArray

            if(routesArray.count > 0)
            {
                var routeDict = routesArray.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
                var routeOverviewPolyline = routeDict.objectForKey("overview_polyline") as! NSDictionary
                var points = routeOverviewPolyline.objectForKey("points") as! String

                var dp = decodePolyline()
                var line = dp.polylineWithEncodedString(points)
                self.mkMapView.addOverlay(line)
            }
```

And Delegate for MKMapView:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
        if overlay is MKPolyline {
            var polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 5
            return polylineRenderer
        }

        return nil
    }
```

I am getting error at  `self.mkMapView.addOverlay(line)`

I have used Objective C class for decode method i have implemented class like:

**decodePolyline.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface decodePolyline : UIViewController

- (MKPolyline*)polylineWithEncodedString:(NSString*)encodedString;

@end
```

**decodePolyline.m**

```
- (MKPolyline*)polylineWithEncodedString:(NSString*)encodedString
{

    NSUInteger length = [encodedString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSUInteger count = length / 4;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D *coords = malloc(count * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
    NSUInteger coordIdx = 0;

    NSMutableString *encoded = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:[encodedString length]];
    [encoded appendString:encodedString];
    [encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"
                                options:NSLiteralSearch
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [encoded length])];
    NSInteger len = [encoded length];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSInteger lat=0;
    NSInteger lng=0;
    while (index < len) {
        NSInteger b;
        NSInteger shift = 0;
        NSInteger result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        NSNumber *latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5];
        NSNumber *longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([latitude doubleValue], [longitude doubleValue]);
        coords[coordIdx++] = coord;
        if (coordIdx == count) {
            NSUInteger newCount = count + 10;
            coords = realloc(coords, newCount * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
            count = newCount;
        }
    }
    MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:coordIdx];
    free(coords);
    return polyline;
}
```

please help me how can i draw route on MKMapView?

Comment: If you are developing a Swift application, you can check out [this Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31352745/4195406). It convert the Google Maps Directions API response to MKPolyline. So that you dont need to use Objective-C file.

Comment: it draws wrong route and also drawing different different route everytime.

Comment: What starting and ending coordinates did you use to test?

Comment: origin=23.0061,72.5647
destination=23.0424,72.5647

Comment: Use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784034/swift-ios-google-map-path-to-coordinate/34435391#34435391